# Multiple Struts 2 configuration files

Tags: java, struts2

I have multiple XML configs.

**struts.xml**

```xml
<struts>
  <include file="struts-user.xml" />

  <package name="baseInterceptors" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptor name="...">
       ...
    </interceptor>
       ...
  </package>

  <package name="default" extends="struts-default,baseInterceptors">
    <action name="...">
       ...
    </action >
       ...
  </package>
</struts>
```

**struts-user.xml**

```xml
<struts>
  <package name="user" extends="struts-default,baseInterceptors">
    <action name="...">
       ...
    </action >
    ...
  </package>
</struts>
```

But the interceptors from `baseInterceptors` are not available in `struts-user.xml`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration files are processed in order: The `<include>` is processed before the `baseInterceptors` and `default` packages are processed (read: defined).

In other words, the included file depends on pacakges that are not yet defined.

The [package configuration docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/package-configuration.html) explain this in a note near the top with an exclamation point next to it.

---

Unrelated, but you've duplicated some configuration, which is misleading/uncommunicative: `baseInterceptors` already extends `struts-default`, so there's no need to extend *both*. Consider creating something like an `application-default` package so it's obvious everything in the app should extend from it. This eliminates unnecessary duplication and communicates your intent.

Comment: I create file `struts-interceptors.xml` and include it in all other files. Thx you

Comment: @gooogenot Cool, glad you worked it out. You don't need to include it in all the other files, though.